# How to identify WMS layers on click

Tags: leaflet, wms

I need to add interactivity to several WMS layers using leaflet, the problem i have is how i can identify what layer the user is clicking,  i usually use geojson for this and is easy, but for WMS layers how i can achieve this?

[I have seen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168628/how-to-capture-a-click-on-a-specific-leaflet-layer), i guess i can iterate over the layers but then again how i can know which one is the one i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WMS layers are raster - which means they are images, even if they have transparent pixels.

In other words: if a user clicks on a transparent pixel on a WMS layer, she is still clicking on the WMS layer. The only exception is clicking outside of the [layer bounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-bounds).

You might want to run a `getFeatureInfo` WMS request on the top-most WMS layer, see if there is any meaningful result at the clicked point, then iterate through other layers.